# How to make an http patch request in angular7 using spring-data-rest endPoint?

Tags: java, json, typescript, angular7, spring-data-rest

I have two entities **"student"** and **"account"** with `@OneToOne` relation, I made an **id_account** foreign key in the **student** table. I tried to change the foreign key value with an HTTP patch request from an angular7 application by calling a spring-data-rest `@RepositoryRestResource` endPoint, But it doesn't update the value of the foreign key.

First I tried to call my endPoint with Postman, and it works fine using a simple call with a JSON body like this:

```
{
"account": "http://localhost:8080/accounts/1"
}
```

But when I tried with my angular app, it doesn't work, and it doesn't give me any kind of error. so how to make this kind of request using httpClient request in angular7?

Here is my code:

**Student entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;


    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account")
    private Account account;
   //Getters and Setters and Constructor
```

**Account entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "account")
    private  Student student;

    //Getters and Setters and Constructor
```

**Student repository:**

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface StudentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Student, Integer> {
}
```

In Client side using angular7
**student.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StudentsService  {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getAll() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/students').pipe(
      map((response: any) => response)
    );
  }

  update(id, account) {

    return this.http.patch(`http://localhost:8080/students/${id}`, account).pipe(
      map((response) => response)
    );
  }
}
```

**students.components.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-students',
  templateUrl: './students.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./students.component.css']
})
export class studentsComponent implements OnInit {

//For testing
id = 2;
account = {id: 1, username: "test", password: "test"} ; 

 constructor(private serviceStudents: StudentsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  update(){
 this.studentService.update(this.id, this.account).subscribe(
  result => console.log(result));
  }    
}
```

Anyone can help me with this problem?

Comment: try to delete pipe and map operators from your service and after that you can get if is there any error.

Comment: @nevzatopcu I deleted the pipe and map, but I still get `null` in the **account_id** in the database.